# Celery unregistered task KeyError

Tags: python, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

I start the worker by executing the following in the terminal:

```
celery -A cel_test  worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n worker1.%h
```

Then I get a long looping error message stating that celery has received an unregistered task and has triggered:

```
KeyError: 'cel_test.grp_all_w_codes.mk_dct' #this is the name of the task
```

The problem with this is that `cel_test.grp_all_w_codes.mk_dct` doesn't exist. In fact there isn't even a module `cel_test.grp_all_w_codes` let alone the task `mk_dct`. There was once a few days ago but I've since deleted it. I thought maybe there was a `.pyc` file floating around but there isn't. I also can't find a single reference in my code to the task that's throwing the error. I shut down my computer and restarted the rabbitmq server thinking maybe a reference to something was just stuck in memory but it did not help.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem here or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, without knowing your conf files, I can see two reasons that would provoke this:

- the `mk_dct` task wasn't completed when you stopped the worker and delete the module. If you're running with [`CELERY_ACKS_LATE`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-acks-late), it will try to relaunch the task everytime you re run the worker. Try remove this setting, or launch the worker with the [purge option.](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-purge-all-waiting-tasks)

`celery -A cel_test  worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n worker1.%h --purge`

- the `mk_dct` task is launched by your celery beat. If so, try relaunching celery beat and clearing it's database backend if you had a custom one.

If it does not solve the problem, please post your celery conf, and make sure you have cleaned all the `.pyc` of your project and restarted everything.

Comment: I had been running `celery purge` from a separate terminal window. After running the worker with the `--purge` option my issue seems to have disappeared.