# How can I get rid of legacy tasks still in the Celery / RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I am running Django + Celery + RabbitMQ. After modifying some task names I started getting "unregistered task" KeyErrors, even after removing tasks with this key from the Periodic tasks table in Django Celery Beat and restarting the Celery worker. They [persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739336/can-celery-tasks-survive-restart) even after [running with the --purge option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892318/celery-unregistered-task-keyerror).

How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 2):

To flush out the last of these tasks, you can re-implement them with their old method headers, but no logic.

For example, if you removed the method `original` and are now getting the error

```
[ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type u'myapp.tasks.original'
```

Just recreate the `original` method as follows:

**tasks.py**

```
@shared_task
def original():
    # keep legacy task header so that it is flushed out of queue
    # FIXME: this will be removed in the next release
    pass
```

Once you have run this version in each environment, any remaining tasks will be processed (and do nothing). Ensure that you have removed them from your *Periodic tasks* table, and that they are no longer being invoked. You can then remove the method before your next deployment, and the issue should no recur.

This is still a workaround, and it would be preferable to be able to [review and delete the tasks individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917413/can-i-review-and-delete-celery-rabbitmq-tasks-individually).